# How to remove gap which comes after a list inside a grid?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple 7x7 grid. The problem is when I place a `<ul>` into the grid cell, it has a large padding after it which I don't know how to remove.

[image: screenshot]

My question is, how to remove that gap?

```css
.date-grid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[7];
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
}

.date-grid .cell {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" class="date-grid">
  <div id="cell00" class="cell">
    <div id="cell00content" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>elso</li>
                <li>masodik</li>
                <li>harom</li>
                <li>negy</li>
                <li>ot</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Entire page:

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS let the height get an auto height with the content

```css
.date-grid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[7];
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    width: 90vw;
    /*height: 90vh;*/ /*with this line you give a fixed height*/
}

.date-grid .cell {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" class="date-grid">
  <div id="cell00" class="cell">
    <div id="cell00content" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>elso</li>
                <li>masodik</li>
                <li>harom</li>
                <li>negy</li>
                <li>ot</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need that because I want the grid to fill the entire page

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem: You want to fill the entire page with the grid, ok. The grid will then take this height (90vh) and divide it by the number of the line it has, so that each line has the same height. So the padding you see under your <ul> block does not come from the <ul> block but it is a padding calculated so that your grid is 90vh high. To realize this you can change the height of the window.

Comment: The problem is the grid doesn't work like you say. If I create an empty grid, then yes, all cells are the same size. But if I put a list into the first cell, then that cell will be larger than the other cells. This is ok, it needs to be larger, because it has a list inside. But why is there a gap after the list?

Comment: I've updated my question and added a screenshot of the entire page. It is ok for the cell to be resized. But why is it resized TOO MUCH?

Comment: If you can share your entire code that we can see on the screenshot, with CodePen or JSFiddle, it will be nice because there is no problem with the simple example that you writed. You can inspect your grid on the Google browser too and maybe see with block put a padding under your <ul> block

Comment: Sure, here's the full HTML: https://codepen.io/gcsaba2/full/BaQmKgG

Comment: The behaviour of the grid is special. With the inspect tool from google I find that your <ul> has default margin value => add ul{margin:0;} in CSS. I told you above that the grid calculates the height of each line. But it calculates this so that to each line the same value will be added. You can see this by reducing the height of your window as much as possible (scrollbar on the right). All your lines will have the same height except the line which will have the minimum height of your list. Then when you slowly enlarge the window you will see that the grid adds the same value to all the lines.

Comment: I see. Yes this makes sense. I mean it still looks weird, I would expect it to keep each cell the same size and only expand the cell once it reaches the threshold. But I agree that currently the gap is there in all cells. If I add the list to several other cells then the whole grid looks somewhat better...